# Subclassing Tkinter.Text to create a custom widget

Tags: python, class, widget, tkinter, inheritance

I am trying to create a text widget with a vertical scrollbar, while retaining all the methods / functions from `Tkinter.Text`.

So far I have the following code:

```
class ScrollableTextWidget(Tkinter.Text):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.Frame = ttk.Frame(self.parent)
        Tkinter.Text.__init__(self, self.Frame, width=1, height=1)
        self.__initWidget()

    def __initWidget(self):
        self.Frame.grid(sticky="NSEW")
        self.ScrollbarY = ttk.Scrollbar(self.Frame, orient="vertical", 
                                        command=self.yview)
        self.configure(yscrollcommand=self.ScrollbarY.set)
        self.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="NSEW")
        self.ScrollbarY.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky="NS")
        self.Frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.Frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Is it OK to create my custom widget like this or should I rather put it in a `Tkinter.frame` and write my own methods?

Answer (score 30):

It's very normal to subclass a widget to create a custom one. However, if this custom widget is made up of more than one widget, you would normally subclass `Frame`. For example, to create a widget that is a text widget with a  scrollbar I would do something like this:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class ScrolledText(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scrolled_text = ScrolledText(self)
        self.scrolled_text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        with open(__file__, "r") as f:
            self.scrolled_text.text.insert("1.0", f.read())

root = tk.Tk()
Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

With this approach, notice how you need to reference the inner text widget when inserting text. If you want this widget to look more like a real text widget, you can create a mapping to some or all of the text widget functions. For example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class ScrolledText(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.text = tk.Text(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.vsb = tk.Scrollbar(self, orient="vertical", command=self.text.yview)
        self.text.configure(yscrollcommand=self.vsb.set)
        self.vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
        self.text.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)

        # expose some text methods as methods on this object
        self.insert = self.text.insert
        self.delete = self.text.delete
        self.mark_set = self.text.mark_set
        self.get = self.text.get
        self.index = self.text.index
        self.search = self.text.search

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.scrolled_text = ScrolledText(self)
        self.scrolled_text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        with open(__file__, "r") as f:
            self.scrolled_text.insert("1.0", f.read())

root = tk.Tk()
Example(root).pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful. I did try to up vote / accept your answer, but unfortunately my reputation is too low. Another thing is, How would I go about to create a ttk.Treeview in the same manner and be able to bind an event to it?, Should I expose and use the treeview instance within the frame?

Comment: The problem with your solution is precisely that you have to manually expose the text member methods, while the OP hoped to get this for free. I, therefore, guess that his original idea of subclassing Text was the right way to go. My Tkinter mastering is too shallow to answer the issue, but I would be glad if someone could do so.

Comment: @user2830098 you don't need any reputation points to accept an answer

Comment: @quickbug: I don’t understand the problem with exposing the text widget methods. Subclassing the text widget is fine if that’s all you want to do, but you don’t want to have to put the scroll bar inside the text widget so you need a container that holds both widgets.

Comment: Something to consider about defining custom widgets this way, is making them work with the universal widget `config()` method. A custom method that routed the various option values to the proper sub-widget based on its name would be needed. While certainly possible to do, it's just another detail that to design, implement, and maintain. Same thing would apply to making a `setitem()` method do the right thing. I believe this would a non-issue or at least be less of one if existing one was subclassed.

Answer (score 2):

I would use subclass for middle, big project  or for project with support in future because subclassing can easy to replace or update. In any case costs for subclassing is small.
But if your task is disposable do  it dirty and quick.

In this case I would subclassing from Frame because it most general widget and not need override `pack`, `grid` and others methods.

Comment: What I am trying to ask is, is it a good practice to subclass the Tkinter.Text (or any other widget to retain it's methods and functions) to create a custom widget. In this case I am subclassing Tkinter.Text, placing it with a scrollbar onto a frame within my class. Or should I subclass Frame and place the Text Widget and scrollbar directly onto it and create my own methods and functions?

Answer (score 0):

Another option for this and other widgets is to import and use the mega widgets in the Pmw( python mega widgets) module. There is  one called ScrolledText which creates a  a text widget with vertical and/or horizontal scroll bars( displayed as text height/width dictates). There are other mega widgets too of course. See docs at https://pmw.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html